# Composite position and size - SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp

I need your help... I attached an image, I want that the right grid appears at the bottom, below of Estadisticas1, Estadisticas2, Estadisticas3, Estadisticas4
I tried a lot of ways, with `GridData`, `FormLayout` and no way!
Also, I tried with `setSize` and `setBounds` and in no cases the size or position change, I don´t know why!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this depending on exactly what you want which you haven't really specified. For example:

```
public void createPartControl(final Composite parent)
{
  Composite body = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

  body.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

  Composite topArea = new Composite(body, SWT.BORDER);

  // TODO add your 'EstadisticasX' controls to 'topArea'

  Composite bottomArea = new Composite(body, SWT.BORDER);

  // TODO add bottom grid to 'bottomArea'
}
```